# Python 2D Array Issue

Tags: python-3.2

I am trying to set a specific value of a 2D array to True. Here is the snippet of code:

```
b [ [False] * 3] * 3
b[2][1] = True
```

Unfortunately, this is setting the entire row to True (so `b[0][1]` would then be changed to True). Any ideas on what is going on?

EDIT:

Just tried this code and it worked:

```
 b = []
 for i in range(3):
     b.append([False, False, False])
 b[1][2] = True
```

Why would it work in that case and not the former?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[False]*3]*3` creates three references to the same `[False,False,False]` object, thus when you change one item, your other rows/cols change as well.

Your second version avoids this by createing a new `[False, False, False]` object for every row/col.